# newtxmath package changing all math font

Tags: math-mode, symbols, packages, math-fonts, newtxmath

I have used `newtxmath` package and experienced some issues, the package is changing the math font in my entire document. Is there a way to use this package for one symbol so its only available locally, when the particular symbol is called.

```
\usepackage{newtxmath}

$\vmathbb{1}$
```

Comment: [Yes, but it’s complicated.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) It gets a lot simpler in `unicode-math`.

Comment: What it sounds like you want to do is declare either a new mathversion that you can change to in one part of your document with `\mathversion{times}`, or else define one symbol as, e.g., ``\varforall` and use it as appropriate. Legacy TeX is limited to only sixteen math alphabets throughout the entire document, however. XeTeX and LuaTeX do not have that limit.